# Voice recognize dialog while ringing phone

Tags: android

I have BroadcastReceiver class which receives the incoming calls. As soon as my phones get incoming call, I would like to fire Voice Recognizer. There will not be any interface to call the RecognizerIntent. Just RecognizerIntent should be invoked automatically while phone is ringing. Is this possible?

I would appreciate if any one share the code for this.

Sravan

Here is what I am trying to do. But its not popping up the Voice recognizer.

```
package srv.phone.calls;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
MediaPlayer mediaPlay;
Toast toast;
private int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.w("DEBUG", state);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.w("DEBUG", phoneNumber);
              // mediaPlay = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sweet);
              // mediaPlay.start();
               toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Call from " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               toast.show();

               Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
               i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                       RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
               i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
               context.startActivity(i); //Not working

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? What works and what doesn't? Do you have any code you would like to share?

Comment: Define "Not working" in the context of that particular line. Are you getting any error messages? Also, I would use `Log.d()` instead of `Log.w()` in this case. Save WARN for things that are bad.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to your intent using `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` before calling `startActivity()`. This is the minimum, you may want some other flags. See [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) for the list.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now it shows up voice recognizer with unknown error. How can catch this error from the activity results.

Comment: Read the logcat. What does it say?

Comment: Now, I am able to call the speech recognition activity from the BroadcastReceiver as shown in my code and it works fine. But how can I get the results (ex:onActivityResult) of this voice recognition activity with in the BroadcastReceiver class ?